# How to select specific number of values from array?

Tags: karate

I have an array, for example, it has 100 length, and I need to select a specific number of values from an array, for example, I want any 5 values from an array.
How to do this?

I saw [Karate : Select 'n' number of random values from an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360630/karate-select-n-number-of-random-values-from-an-array) but here I don't provide a specific number of values. So this is not my case(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This becomes a JS problem. I'll just provide one option that may be sufficient. Here we get 2 random elements.

```
* def data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
* def filtered = data.filter(x => Math.random() < 0.5)
* def selected = filtered.slice(0, 2)
```

You are welcome to write a more robust function, refer this answer: [How to get a number of random elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19269545/143475)

Comment: I took the next: 
  * def filtered = slugList.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
  * def selected = filtered .slice(0, 2)
And it works ok for me because the previous shows me the same result (has only 2-3 combinations), for some reason(