# Writing a condition in UI Test using Karate

Tags: testing, karate

It doesn't look that simple? I don't know if Karate is made for this kind of thing. Is it possible to discriminate with Karate by using 'if' 'else' like this for example?

I want to create a test that can integrate 2 possible scenarios using the 'Outline' feature
However, each test persona has different actions to execute. So I'm wondering if it's possible to create a condition that describes actions for each persona.

```
# connection
Given driver 'http://localhost:3000/login'
And input('#username', 'john.doe')
And input('#password', 'password123')

# click connection button
When click('#login-button')

# check message
Then if (driver.text('#welcome-message') == 'Hello, John !')
    // stuff persona 1
else
    // stuff persona 2
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Yes karate encourages you to NOT put logic in your tests. `if` statements are supported on a single line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76701268/143475

If you really wanted you could break out into pure JS, but there are pros and cons.

```
* eval
"""
if (condition) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
"""
```

The UI testing syntax has all the checks you typically need, for example: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#exists